# JPG aplha maps with Cycles

Tags: texturing

I searched everywhere and I can't find an answer on how to do this with Blender and Cycles:

- I have a pre-made model with textures
- Some materials have a Diffuse map (JPG) with a separate Alpha Map, another JPG.

What kind of texture setup do I need to make these two maps give me a texture with alpha that I can use in a Cycles material?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: jpegs cant have an alpha channel. My guess is that your second jpeg is a luma map (Just black and white).

Comment: @Dontwalk I think he means the alpha map came as a separate image file, rather than an alpha channel in a PNG or other supported file format. That being said the setup is no different from other transparent materials.

Comment: @ Duarte Farrajota Ramos - He said he got two jpegs so there cant be an Alpha Channel or transparency. I'm guessing (without seeing the files) that one of the jpegs is just B&W to be used as a Mask.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you just need to use the output of the second texture (Alpha Map) as the alpha. For example: using it as the transparency:
[image]

Note that the Alpha is Non-Color Data